# Stemming words in a Python list

Tags: python, nlp, stemming

Have a list "l" with distinct words like this:

```
'gone',
'done',
'crawled',
'laughed',
'cried'
```

I try to apply stemming on this list just that way:

```
from stemming.porter2 import stem
l = [[stem(word) for word in sentence.split(' ')] for sentence in l]
```

But nothing seems to happen and nothing changes. What am I doing wrong with the stemming procedure?

Comment: It looks to me like you are iterating one level too deep. `l` is a list of words, not sentences, and there doesn't seem to be anything to split.

Comment: if `l` is a list of single words you shouldn't be splitting it using `sentence.split(' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has one mistake. `l` is a list of words, not sentences. You have to do this:

```
l = [stem(word) for word in l]
```

For example:

```
>>> l = ['gone', 'done', 'crawled', 'laughed', 'cried']
>>> [stem(word) for word in l]
['gone', 'done', 'crawl', 'laugh', 'cri']
```